# Boundary condition for Green's function

Tags: electrostatics, voltage, gauss-law, boundary-conditions, greens-functions

Suppose we have an equation $\nabla^2V = -\rho/\epsilon_0$ and the boundary condition for $V$ is given. I have a question regarding the boundary condition for Green's function for this equation. What determines the boundary conditions for the Green's function? Why should we choose a particular boundary condition?

Comment: The boundary conditions depend on your problem - so no general answer can be given to this question.

Comment: I've edited the question to be more directly answerable, since as originally posed the literal answer was "there is no general answer".  Feel free to revert these edits if it changes your meaning too much.

Comment: aren’t boundary conditions also known as “initial conditions”?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero:  For problems where time is one of the independent variables, yes.  But you can also talk about boundary conditions in a purely spatial problem, such as finding the electric potential in a region given the potential on the boundaries.  In that context "initial conditions" isn't quite the right term.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert right but I was trying to illustrate the point that boundary conditions are specified at the start of each problem...

Answer (score 3):

The Green's function for this problem is a generalized function that satisfies the equation $\nabla^2 G(x,x') = -\delta(x-x')$. We want it to satisfy boundary conditions such that we can write the solution $V$ to the general problem as
$$V(x) = \int_\Omega G(x,x') \frac{\rho(x')}{\epsilon_0} d x'.$$

From the equations above, we see that we can interpret the Green's function $G(x,x')$ as the potential that arises at the point $x$ due to a point charge at the position $x'$, and that we can write the full potential $V$ as a superposition of these point-charge potentials.

If $V$ has to satisfy homogeneous boundary conditions of some sort (e.g. Dirichlet or Neumann), this can be guaranteed by imposing the *same* boundary conditions on $G$ viewed as a function of its first argument.
In the case of Dirichlet boundary conditions, for instance, we require that
$V(x) = 0$ when $x \in \partial \Omega$, and we should then require that $G(x,x')=0$ when $x \in \partial \Omega$.

How do we then treat inhomogeneous BCs? Well, the typical approach is to divide the problem in two. Say that we require $V(x) = f(x)$ when $x\in \partial \Omega$. Then we can write $V(x) = V_\rho(x) + V_\text{hom}(x)$ where
$$\nabla^2 V_\text{hom}(x) = 0, \qquad V_\text{hom}(x) = f(x) \text{  when  } x \in \partial \Omega,$$

$$\nabla^2 V_\rho(x) = -\frac{\rho}{\epsilon_0}, \qquad V_\rho(x) = 0 \text{  when  } x \in \partial \Omega.$$

We can then use the Green's function to find $V_\rho$, which satisfies homogeneous BCs, and separately solve the Laplace equation for $V_\text{hom}$ with the specified inhomogeneous BC.